# Automating compatibility testing against many programs

Tags: testing, automated-tests, compatibility

Short version: What's the best way to automate compatibility testing
against a large number of third-party programs?

The details:

I develop a [program](https://launchpad.net/panflute) whose core feature is interacting with a variety of
different pieces of music player software via their respective RPC
interfaces.  The RPC itself typically happens either via D-Bus or via some
client library specific to a particular player.  Since each music player
has its own unique RPC interface, my program requires special code to
handle each.

Testing all this code is increasingly a problem for me.  At last count
there are fifteen (!) different music players my program knows how to talk
to, and the interface details can vary from one version of a player to the
next.  Manually testing my program against the latest version of each of
the players I'm trying to support, as well as a few older versions, is
tedious and error-prone, so I'm looking for a way to automate this as much
as possible.

The test cases themselves aren't the problem; those are just a matter of
calling a sequence of functions on a player's RPC interface and checking
the return values and/or asynchronous callbacks for the expected result.
No, the problem is having a framework to run the tests automatically.

Here are the challenges I see:

- Each player maintains persistent state, usually as dotfiles under the
  user's home directory.  The state consists of things like the music
  library, playlists, etc.  These files need to be reverted to a known
  initial state before each test.  (Deleting it entirely isn't always an 
  option, since then the GUI-based players will present a setup wizard the
  next time they start instead of running normally.)
- Those initial states may be partially dynamic.  For example, a music
  library will contain full paths to the music files within it, but the
  paths to the actual "music" files used for testing will vary from
  machine to machine and won't be known until runtime.
- The players to test against will probably be installed under
  non-standard locations which will vary from system to system, in order
  to have multiple versions of each installed in parallel.  The framework
  will probably need to know which player and version it's testing against
  before the player is started, so it can initialize the player's state 
  files accordingly.
- Since I don't have any control over development of the music players my
  program interacts with, I can't modify their behavior to make it easier
  for me to test against them.

What I'd like to do is set up a VM with a bunch of different players (and
a bunch of different versions of each player) installed, and then be able
to test my program against each of them in turn automatically.  Ideally, 
it would be possible for someone else to set up their own VM to run tests
in themselves, presumably only needing to tell the test framework which
players are installed where.

So, **what's the best way to automate compatibility testing against a large
number (several dozen) of third-party programs?**

In case it affects the recommendations, my program is written in Python, 
and I'm using GNU autotools as the build framework.

Answer (score 0):

If this only windows environment there is one way to go and that is with MS Hyper-V.

Link(http://www.microsoft.com/virtualization/en/us/solution-application-development.aspx)

They have support for having a image of for example of a Vista installation and by scripting creating a new copy of it and push an installation into the new image and have a basic installation + added software up and running within minutes.

The MS Office team use this and test engineers can order any version, language edition of windows in combination of any release of office within a few minutes..

Big problem is that this cost a good bit of money and Hyper-V is a quite complex product to set up.

As an alternative maybe could be to use Virtual Box (Open Source) and write your own script to automate installations of an image with new versions of software for test. I have done this with the standard image reading script upon start up from a network folder to install any software for test.. Its not fully automated solution but saved my team a lot of time.

Comment: This is Linux, so Hyper-V isn't an option.  I ended up setting up a VM (using kvm) with my various targets installed in parallel, with custom test harness to reset their configurations for each test.  I was hoping there'd be some existing tool for this, as the harness has been a nontrivial thing to create.